# Get the exit of maze using stack in C

Tags: c, matrix, binary

I have an algorithm that search for a exit of a maze using recursive function , how i pass this to a function without recursive but using stack?What this algorithm do is basically , try to found the exit of  a matriz , if the next step is 0 or if has already been covered comeback and try another path, but a i need to change the recursive function to a function using stack instead of recursion how i do that?

```
    void print_maze(char **maze, int width, int height) {

for (int i=0; i<13; i++ ){
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++ )
  {
     printf ("%d", maze[i][j]);
  }
printf("\n");
}
}

int maze(int x_current, int y_current,char **mazeHere, int height,int width)
{
    if (x_current < 0 || x_current >= width || y_current < 0 || y_current >= height)
        return 0;

        char here = mazeHere[x_current][y_current];
        if (here == 3)
        return 1;

        if(here == 0 || here == 2)
            return 0;


        mazeHere[x_current][y_current] = 2;
         if(maze(x_current ,y_current-1,mazeHere,height,width))return 1;
        if(maze(x_current+1,y_current,mazeHere,height,width))return 1;
        if(maze(x_current,y_current+1,mazeHere,height,width))return 1;

          if(maze(x_current-1,y_current,mazeHere,height,width))return 1;



       else{ mazeHere[x_current][y_current] = 1;
            return 0;
       }

}


int main(void)
{
char matriz [13][10]={
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0},
{0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},
{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
{0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,3},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},};
int b= 0;
int height = 10;
int width = 13;
int p = 0;
int o = 0;
char **a = malloc(width * sizeof(char*));
for(int x = 0; x< width; x++){
    a[x] = malloc(height * sizeof(char));
}


for (int i=0; i<13; i++ ){
  for (int j=0; j<10; j++ )
  {
      a[i][j]= matriz[i][j];
  }

}



int res = maze(4,0,a,height,width);
    puts(res ? "success!" : "no luck!");
print_maze(a, width, height);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, https://repl.it/@lrfer/ShadowySickUnderstanding#main.c

Comment: I am not going to click the link.  The problem statement in your post is not clear.  I suggest you write it out in your own tongue, and use Google translate to convert to English, then re-post.  Be sure to describe how the current code does not work.  If the current code does work, then you do not have a problem, and it is off-topic to ask others to write it for you.

Comment: The thing an explicit stack gains you is primarily the same thing that the (implicit) call stack gets you in a recursive approach: a separate set of local variable values for each step of the procedure.  The general idea, then, is that you loop instead of recursing, using a stack to preserve the values of those local variables that need to be preserved.  In your particular case, since you make multiple recursive calls you'll need also for the stack to store some kind of indicator of where you are in the procedure.  But no, I won't write it for you.

Comment: Just make a function that does only one move in the maze and then in the `main` call this function into a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it's hard without recursion. By the way, conversion from recursion into using stack is not so hard, if you wrote code of stack data structure and its operation. We are going to pursue the matter on the assume.

Recursive function basically has structure like this:

```
position *seek(position *now, type arg...){
    ...
    if(condition){
        return NULL;
    } else {
        now->next = seek(arg_next);
    }
}
```

It's OK to understand just with your feeling. What it does here is chaining new result to results until now. In other words, storing results as data structure. Here, data structure changes to stack. Then...:

```
void seek(stack *stack, type arg...){
    ...
    while(1){
        if(condition){
            break;
        } else {
            stack->push(next_result)
        }
    }
}
```

It's so easy! All that is left is increasing conditions and considering backtracking. Based on the above, try to rewrite your code!

Comment: Work, thanks
https://repl.it/@lr_fernando/HonorableSmoothMinimalsystem#main.c